# ¿Como realizar busqueda en mysql con codeigniter segun valor de input?

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo una duda sobre como mostrar los registros dependiendo de que categoria sea:
Tabla categoria:
idCategoria nombreCategoria
1           Espalda
2           Pecho
3           Piernas y Gluteos
4           Core
5           Brazos

Tabla Ejercicio:
idEjercicio nombreEjercicio     imagenEjercicio urlEjercicio    idCategoria estadoEjercicio
1       Flexiones inclinadas    NULL        NULL        2       Activo
2       Press Banco Inclinado   NULL        NULL        2       Activo

en la vista muestro un panel por categoria, en el el nombre de la categoria y un input con el id que pienso usar para filtrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como puedo hacer para que me muestre solo los ejercicios que corresponden a cada categoria?

Comment: Necesitas pasarle a la función `sel_ejercicios()` el **idCategoria** para poder añadirlo en un `where` en la **query**.

Comment: Si. Pero¿ como enviar el valor del input si no hay un submit? . El filtro debiera ser automático.

Comment: Tendría q usar ajax?